# Azure ML release bug AZUREML_COMPUTE_USE COMMON_RUNTIME

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, mlops

On 2021-10-13 in our application in Azure ML platform we get this new error that causes failures in pipeline steps - python module import failures - [warning stack <- warning that leads to pipeline runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Jeb.png)

we needed to set it to false. Why is it failing? What exactly are exact (and long term) consequences when opting out? Also, Azure ML users - do you think it was rolled out appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add into your envirnoment new variable like this:

```
environment.environment_variables = {"AZUREML_COMPUTE_USE_COMMON_RUNTIME":"false"}
```

Comment: Sure - I just can not really understand the consequences for my PROD env? What's AML common runtime? what if I don't migrate my pipelines to that runtime? 

For other people - Wazza is talking about is adding env var to your pipelines step runconfig, ex: 

`run_config = RunConfiguration()`  `run_config.environment.environment_variables["AZUREML_COMPUTE_USE_COMMON_RUNTIME"]="false"`  `step = PythonScriptStep(runconfig=run_config,...)`  `pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=aml_workspace, steps=[...,step,...])`

Answer (score 0):

Long term (throughout 2022), AzureML will be fully migrating to the new Common Runtime on AmlCompute. Short term, this change is a large undertaking, and we're on the lookout for tricky functionality of the old Compute Runtime we're not yet handling correctly.

One small note on disabling Common Runtime, it can be more efficient (avoids an Environment rebuild) to add the environment variable directly to the `RunConfig`:

```
run_config.environment_variables["AZUREML_COMPUTE_USE_COMMON_RUNTIME"] = "false"
```

We'd like to get more details about the import failures, so we can fix the regression. Are you setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to make your custom scripts importable? If so, this is something we're aware isn't working as expected and are looking to fix it within the next two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

We identified the issue and have rolled out a hotfix on our end addressing the issue. There are two problems that could've caused the import issue. One is that we are overwriting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. The second is that we are not adding the python script's containing directory to python's module search path if the containing directory is not the current working directory.

It would be great if you can please try again without setting the `AZUREML_COMPUTE_USE_COMMON_RUNTIME` environment variable and see if the problem is still there. If it is, please reply to either Lucas's thread or mine with a minimal repro or description of where the module you are trying to import is located at in relation to the script being run and the root of the snapshot (which is the current working directory).